# Text color of list not changing

Tags: html, css

Text color of list is not changing. I'm not sure why. I made the links a class `nav` and tried to style that with CSS but it doesn't seem to take effect.

#### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="####" class="nav">info</a></li>
    <li><a href="###"  class="nav">facebook</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
ul {
    padding-top: 6%;
    right: 9%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
}

a .nav {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #1B1B1B !important;
}
```

Comment: Because you have a space between a and .nav.  Should be a.nav, or better yet just .nav

Comment: in some browsers you have a developer tool (chrome or opera). You can right click on your link and choose "inspect element" – it will show you some more detailed information on how the browser *sees* your links and what *CSS* is used (and which CSS code gets ignored). Maybe some CSS is overriding the color again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a .nav` needs to be `a.nav`.

`a .nav` looks for any element with the class `nav` that is a descendant of an anchor. `a.nav` selects anchors that have the class nav.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k3kyg/)**

Also, whenever possible, try to avoid using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Your element selector  `a .nav` had space, change it to :

```
a.nav {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #1B1B1B;
}
```

or like this one :

```
.nav a{
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #1B1B1B !important;
}
```